# How to distinguish Firefox 52 ESR from Firefox 52 by javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

Firefox do not support NPAPI plugins except Flash since ver.52
but Firefox 52 ESR still support such plugin

I get browser info by calling [navigator.userAgent] in my js code
But on both Firefox 52 and Firefox 52 ESR they are all the same as follows:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0

So, how can I distinguish Firefox 52 ESR from Firefox 52 by javascript

Comment: I don't get it, why would you want to detect it by js if it's for a plugin ? (Note, I'm unaware of NPAPI world)

Comment: The plugin is used for a certain website and if it not supported, I would like to show some tips

Comment: can't you just disable these tips from your plugin? If it fires it means that the plugin is not there. (sorry I have only that which came at the top of my head).

Comment: Thanks for your smart solution Kaiido. But I still wonder if there is a simpler way as judging it by JavaScript

Comment: How you installed the Firefox ESR? In same system? Which one first and which one second?

Comment: I installed them separately in one system(win8 64). Firefox 52 first, and then ESR.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674004/how-to-detect-difference-between-firefox-and-firefox-esr-in-javascript